# Как автоматизировать последовательность действий в Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, google-docs

Мне необходимо получить данные со страницы https://iss.moex.com/iss/history/engines/stock/markets/shares/boards/TQBR/securities.xml?iss.meta=off&iss.only=marketdata&start=0 в google-таблицу.
Делаю это с помощью apps script. Но бывают периоды, когда данные не загружаются. Видимо, сервер не отдаёт по ip адресам, которые использует apps script.

Вручную, в браузере всё нормально загружается.

Подскажите направление в котором искать - как автоматизировать загрузку трёх страниц в браузере - с параметрами &start=0, &start=100 и &start=200 на конце, забрать данные с этих страниц и поместить их в гугл-таблицу?

Comment: Используйте прокси или любую прокладку с функцией прокси. Вопрос не имеет четких границ. Это не по правилам сообщества.